# Collision Question: Does this padding protect vase that's travelling in a truck travelling at 60 km/h that abruptly comes to rest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

> **Question: Could a packaging material bring a 1.45 kg vase to rest safely (an average force less than 2.00 x 10^2), if the vase is travelling in a shipping truck travelling at 60 km/h that abruptly comes to rest?**

*Please let me know if my approach to this question makes sense.

*Fav has been updated... sorry for the confusion

Additional info:
6 cm of padding and the average force reduced by the packaging material during collision is given (but I need to calculate that)
Because I'm given info to calculate the average force before and after collision with and without the packaging material

My thoughts:

I recognize that

$m_{\rm vase} = 1.45 \ \rm kg$

$v_{i,\rm \ truck} =  \rm 60 \ km/h = 16.67 \ m/s$

$v_{f\rm, \ truck} = 0$

F = 2.00 x 10^2 N

---

Updated thoughts

Would it be correct to think:

Since Δp = FavΔt = mΔv
then, Fav = m(Δv/Δt), where Δv is 60 km/h of the vase and Fav is 2.00 x 10^2N

I rearrange to find Δt (1)

Then, using Fav = m(Δv/Δt), where Δv is 60 km/h of the vase and Fav is ____ of the packaging that I will calculate, I find Δt (2)

If Δt (1) < Δt (2) then the packaging won't protect vase

---

---

Thoughts before

I feel like impulse will be needed to solve part of the problem...

But I'm having trouble figuring out:

1. How does stopping the truck affect the vase in the box? I assume the vase would move forwards [relative to the earth, if we're observing the side of truck] then collide into the packaging. But I'm not sure what that would mean for the vase's velocity, acceleration, etc.
2. If I'm correct about impulse, what would the time be?
   And would we rearrange the equation of impulse to isolate for Fav and see if it equals 2.00 x 10^2?

---

Below is formula for impulse:
$F = m(v_f-v_i)$ or

$$\Delta p = F\Delta t$$

Comment: Hi, and to the community! If possible, try to type your question instead of using images or screenshots. For equations, you can use MathJax. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a **very** poorly worded problem.  I guess I'd hope the intent was that the truck stops with a delta function, and then you want to provide packaging which spreads that delta force over a long-enough time period that the vase survives.  But the answer to that is "of course," since no limits were placed on the type of packaging or the size of packaging.  Imagine something as simple as 100 meters of compressible foam!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : But 100 m packaging for a truck is not realistic. My calculation shows that the minimum packaging size is about 15 cm, which is realistic, so the wording of the problem seems reasonable.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft 
Just included that there's 6 cm of padding and the average force reduced by the packaging material during collision is given (but I need to calculate that). Also, I updated the average force stated in the question.

Comment: @akhmeteli  that restriction was not provided when I commented

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, I didn't comment that restriction until I read both of your comments. But with the extra info I'm still not sure how to approach this problem...

Answer (score 2):

You know the maximum force the vase can withstand and the vase mass, so you know the maximum vase acceleration; you also know the velocity change, so you know the minimum time until the vase stops. Then you can calculate the minimum distance the vase moves until it stops. Does the distance look realistic as packaging size?